# How to monitor file downloads in python?

Tags: python, download, monitor, gateway, snort

I have a two virtual machines, one with 2 network adaptaters (windows server), one connected to internet and the other to a LAN. The second virtual machine (windows client is connected to the LAN and has access to internet through the other vm which is used as a gateway/server.

I need to write a python code that detect whenever a file is downloaded so that I can identify anomalies and then send to the server informations about the file. I'm struggling with the first step (detect any downlaods).
I used snort to monitor network traffic, I can write rules so that an alert is logged whenever a file is downloaded but I need to incorporate this in my python application or use an other method.

Does anyone have any suggestion ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and you should (re-)read the help topic [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get a feeling on how to contribute. You should at least make an own attempt to get your task done and share the code here. Even if you don't have a good knowledge about Python.

Comment: I don't know how I could do it, that's the question. I'm not asking for code but a method/advices which will allow me to do it or just to know if it's possible

Comment: @Ottman , i suggest you to see `socket` module in python

Answer (score 1):

You can use watchdog to monitor file changes, moves, etc:

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    pa = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    obs = Observer()
    obs.schedule(event_handler, pa, recursive=True)
    obs.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        obs.stop()
    obs.join()
```

Comment: I'll look into this solution, thank you for your answer. If anyone has an other idea that does not involve file monitoring but network monitoring, I'm still interested.